# Equation of a bicycle Wheel in free rotation up to stop

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, friction

I have measured the rotational speed of a bicycle wheel in free rotation up to stop and i would like to have the physical equation (it is not linear). I would like to compute the frictional losses in the  bearing.

Comment: Here's a place to start: https://www.khanacademy.org/science/physics/torque-angular-momentum/rotational-kinematics/v/rotational-kinematic-formulas

Comment: This link provides basic rotational formulaes true only for a constante acceleration (or deceleration). In my cas the curve i got is not linear, somewhere between exponential and t^2.

Comment: If you conduct an experiment with a real bicycle wheel, you should be able to collect data in an approximately linear range while the wheel is slowing down.  This should give you enough information to calculate bearing friction, which should be linear.  Any non-linearities are probably due to air drag, which is known to be quadratic when parts of the wheel are causing turbulence.

Comment: I found a starting point in this ppaer "Friction modeling of a free-spinning bicycle wheel"
https://www.eng.mu.edu/nagurka/HuangNagurka_FrictionModelingOct%202003_PaperTRIB-265.pdf
but the physical model proposed Jw'+Bw+T=0 does not match well the data.
I think there should be a parameter to model air drag, so i guess an equation like this
Jw'+A.w²+Bw+Tc=0.
If some could help me to solve this type of equation to get w(t)

Comment: For the front wheel i get B=0.0008, Tc=0.0025; for the rear wheel i get B=0.003, Tc=0.005. How can i compute the losses in Watt, knowing this friction torque ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have knowledge of the wheel's angular velocity $\omega(t)$ as a function of time, then the frictional torque on the wheel (as a function of time) must be given by
$$
\tau(t) = I \frac{d \omega}{dt}.
$$
This equation holds even if the frictional torque is not constant.

In practice, if your data is sampled at a series of discrete time separated by $\Delta t$, then you will have to approximate $d\omega/dt$ using a [finite-difference approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference).